# Red Bipartita - Indice "weighted nestedness"

Tags: r, r-bipartite

Estoy tratando de sacar algunos estadísticos de mi red bipartita y me doy cuenta que el índice "weighted nestedness" varia cada vez que ejecuto el código. Utilizo la función `networklevel` de la librería `bipartite`

`networklevel(mp, index = c("connectance", "linkage density", "links per species","weighted nestedness","weighted NODF", "ISA"))`

Alguien puede aclararme porqué?

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

La explicación formal de por que él índice "weighted nestedness"  es distinto en cada oportunidad que ejecutas `networklevel()`, escapa a mi conocimiento y seguramente a la temática del sitio. La documentación del estimador [`wine()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/bipartite/versions/2.15/topics/wine) usado en este índice seguramente dice algo. Sin embargo en lo que respecta a lo estrictamente relacionado con la programación, lo que puede saberse viendo el [código fuente](https://github.com/cran/bipartite/blob/master/R/wine.r)  es que el estimador usa funciones que dependen del generador de números aleatorios de R, en este caso `sample()` , lo que hace que la función finalmente sea "no determinística", es decir, con los mismos valores de entrada no puedes esperar el mismo resultado.

Básicamente lo que se observa:

```
library("bipartite")

data(Safariland)

networklevel(Safariland, index = c("weighted nestedness"))
networklevel(Safariland, index = c("weighted nestedness"))

weighted nestedness 
          0.3811674 
weighted nestedness 
          0.3801909
```

Si quisieras transformar la ejecución en algo "determinístico" puedes prefijar la semilla inicial del generador de números aleatorios:

```
set.seed(2019)
networklevel(Safariland, index = c("weighted nestedness"))
set.seed(2019)
networklevel(Safariland, index = c("weighted nestedness"))

weighted nestedness 
          0.4039553 
weighted nestedness 
          0.4039553
```